# Magento2 custom attribute for specific product type

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, custom-attributes

When creating attribute I notice that in magento2 no option for the select product type.

i.e I want my attribute will available for configurable product only.

But that attribute is visible for all simple product too.

Even I create a custom attribute when creating adding a configurable product.

When adding a simple product why that attribute is visible?

*** How to create an attribute for configurable product only?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes , You can create specific attribute for specific product type programmatically.

Below i have created Boolean type of attribute for configurable product only.

You need to pass **'apply_to'** parameter and its value as **configurable**

**try below code in your InstallData.php file :**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'attribute_for_config',
            [
                'group' => 'Product Details',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'sort_order' => 50,
                'label' => 'Can be wrapped?',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to'=>'configurable'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**Note :** Same way if you needed this for all types of product you need to pass **all values in same parameters like :  'apply_to'=>'simple,configurable,bundle,grouped'**

Comment: k, thanks. by the way can i edit an attribute if already create ?

Comment: Yes you can edit/update attribute by create UpgradeData.php file. refer this link for more reference about updatescript -
 http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/02/09/installation-and-upgrade-scripts-in-magento-2/

Comment: 1 more question. I have to create the new module or it will work with module already installed? Because code will be write in installData.php ? or i have to write in upgradedata.php I was create a new module as mention in given above link. but module was not creating table in database.

Comment: well we have created attribute for product , so there is no issue with the module which is installed. but still if you want to do it with your module then copy your installData file in your module and delete the one which we have created, make sense ?

Comment: as you said i wrote the code in InstallData.php but new attribute not added. Can you tell me exactly where i have to write above given code? I am okey if work when i write code in other module's file

Comment: Its working now. Actually i write it in upgradedata.php and after update version of module in module.xml & upgradedata.php its working. So can you please mention this thing in your answer. So people who is very new can understand it quickly

Comment: i was successful to add a boolean type attribute but when try to add a dropdown type attribute it's not working. Changed **type** from **varchar** to **int** and **input** from **boolean** to **select** `'type' => 'int'` `'input' => 'select',`

Comment: solved it myself. thank you for your support

Comment: Happy To help , Keep helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Next time use Mage2Gen https://mage2gen.com/

You can easily create a module with Mage2Gen which installs Product Attributes and if you configure the Advanced options  you can specify the Allowed Product Types.

Sample Test Attribute

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'test',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Test',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => 1,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => null,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'configurable',
            'system' => 1,
            'group' => 'General',
            'option' => array('values' => array(""))
        ]
    );
```