# How to Create Product Attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes

I use Magento 2.2.6 with a theme on shared hosting. This query is about how to create Product attribute?

When I started exploring and creating a test configurable product, I found Color attribute by default in Default Attribute set. Color attribute is available only when we click on create configuration button during new product creation.

I created Volume attribute with 3 values and Potency with 7 values. I face following issue.

> 1- Both the values are visible when creating normal products and gets
>   assigned when it is not required. Adding unnecessary values to
>   products.
>
> 2- Why My attributes are visible in normal configuration but color is
>   only available when we click on create configuration.
>
> 3- Do I need to create a separate attribute set with required
>   attributes?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove it from Admin Panel, Go to Stores->Attribute set and Move your attribute pull out from the left side list to unassigned attributes.

Comment: I have tried this earlier. I get following error. Attribute 'potency' is locked. This attribute is used in configurable products.

Comment: there no way to hide that attribute only for simple products, you have to delete that attribute and recreate it with type "filterable with results" and don't assign to the default attribute set.

Comment: When we create and assign any attribute to a configurable product, at the time of save it asks to assign to available attribute set. cant avoid that.

Comment: Then you have do it using code, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182710/magento2-custom-attribute-for-specific-product-type

Comment: can you please tell me how to remove default value selection radio. 250ml and 1000ch are default value. If i uncheck the radio, issue will be resolved.

Comment: In backed that option will be selected, so dleete all option and recreate all those option without selecting any radio button then save that attibute ..check whether it will workout or not..

Comment: deleting and recreating will not work. All the configurable products will go bad. I have tried this. There over 200 configurable products which needs to be recreated.